# Windows 7 64-bit Web Cam drivers for a Sony Vaio VGN-AR41S?

Tags: windows-7, drivers, sony-vaio

Anyone know where I can get a Windows 7 64-bit driver for my Web Cam (Sony Vaio VGN-AR41S) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer : http://readmystuff.wordpress.com/2009/09/28/sony-vaio-vgn-ar41s-motion-eye-driver-for-windows-7-64bit/